Swagger UI not working in Spring Boot Project
I was following a Java project tutorial by Telusko and did things exactly the way he had done. However, my code doesn't take me to the Swagger when I visit http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.
I looked into every possible solution but no of them could help me fix this problem I have been facing to setup the swagger API for my spring boot project.
In my project, I have put the following dependencies of spring-boot in pom.xml
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

Following are my swagger dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

Here is my spring boot maven plugin:
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

I have made my main file look this:
package com.prashant.joblisting;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class JoblistingApplication {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class)).paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo()).useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        final ApiInfoBuilder builder = new ApiInfoBuilder();
        return builder.build();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JoblistingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

This is how my controller file looks like:
package com.prashant.joblisting;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class PostController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/swagger-ui.html");
    }
}

When I run my application this is what my console shows:
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.3.0)

2024-06-04T14:40:56.784-04:00  INFO 23660 --- [joblisting] [           main] c.p.joblisting.JoblistingApplication     : Starting JoblistingApplication using Java 21.0.1 with PID 23660 (C:\Users\prash\Downloads\joblisting\joblisting\target\classes started by prash in C:\Users\prash\Downloads\joblisting)
2024-06-04T14:40:56.788-04:00  INFO 23660 --- [joblisting] [           main] c.p.joblisting.JoblistingApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-06-04T14:40:57.504-04:00  WARN 23660 --- [joblisting] [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
2024-06-04T14:40:57.511-04:00  INFO 23660 --- [joblisting] [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-06-04T14:40:57.525-04:00 ERROR 23660 --- [joblisting] [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.computeSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperInterfaces(ClassRepository.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getGenericInterfaces(Class.java:1296) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.getInterfaces(ResolvableType.java:517) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.as(ResolvableType.java:465) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.core.ResolvableType.forClass(ResolvableType.java:1093) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.getTargetType(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:101) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.plugin.core.config.PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(PluginRegistriesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:71) ~[spring-plugin-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:86) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:376) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:375) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:148) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:429) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:290) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.0.jar:3.3.0]
    at com.prashant.joblisting.JoblistingApplication.main(JoblistingApplication.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114) ~[na:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1

This is what my folder structure looks like for this project:
File System in this project
I did everything in the tutorial. I also followed geeksforgeeks blog but none of those took me to the Swagger UI. I followed through bunch of past stackoverflow questions and none of them helped either.

SpringFox doest work with spring boot 3.0, change your parent on pom file to spring version compatible like 2.5. I had example on this GitHub https://github.com/lukkascost/Experiments_IA_Data/blob/master/dataset.module/pom.xml

Springfox and Springdoc are incompatible, both do the same thing. Remove one and keep the other one. I recommend keeping Springdoc.

@LucasCosta i tried to configure the way you mentioned here is my code: https://github.com/prashantjerk/spring-boot-joblist/tree/main/joblisting/src/main/java/com/prashant/joblisting
When I navigate to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
I get the error This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Can you please help me?

Its because you use springfox 3.0.0 with its not compatible, just change the version to 2.9.2 and will works on http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

For the integration between spring-boot and swagger-ui, delete all Springfox related dependencies and just add the following library to the list of your project dependencies (No additional configuration is needed):
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

The Swagger UI page will then be available at
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html


Thanks alot. Can you also provide any links that can help me do some customisation to this?

What kind of customization? If you want to make minor customizations like excluding any api points, you can do it with the help of annotations. Apart from that i think you will have to refer docs for more..
